# Limit number of selected cells by section in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

I've spent a lot of time searching a solution to limit the number of selected cells in a `UITableView`.

Here is a piece of code I found :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        if selectedRows.count == limit {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

The problem is that `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` contains selected cells that are VISIBLE and from any section.

Does a property like : `tableView.selectedCellsForSection(section: 0)` exist ?

Thanks for your help !

**UPDATE 1**

This is an example with a car that containts several options

```
var selectedOptions = [IndexPath : Option]() // Option can be for example, the color of the car

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    let maxOptionForSection = car.options![indexPath.section]?.max
    let numberOfSelectedOptions = selectedOptions.filter { $0.key.section == indexPath.section }

    if numberOfSelectedOptions.count == maxOptionForSection {
        return nil
    }

    return indexPath
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? OptionCell {
        cell.checkButton.isChecked = true
        cell.option.isSelected = true
        selectedOptions[indexPath] = cell.option
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? OptionCell {
        cell.checkButton.isChecked = false
        cell.option.isSelected = false
        selectedOptions.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let optionCell = cell as! OptionCell

    if optionCell.option.isSelected {
        optionCell.checkButton.isChecked = true
    } else {
        optionCell.checkButton.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just filter from that array? tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.filter({ $0.section == section })

Comment: Can you explain me what this line means please ? I don't understand `{ $0.row == section }`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, should be { $0.section == section }. In this case section is your variable (0 in the question). It indicates that for every indexPath in the array, if the section is the same as the variable section it should be kept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will limit it to the section in which the row was clicked:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section }) {
        if selectedRows.count == limit {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: It works, but because of the cells recycle I think, something strange occurs. I have a tableView that contains 4 section with different numbers of row : 1 = 4 rows, 2 = 6 rows, 3 = 2 rows and 4 = 6 rows. When I select the very first row (0, 0) and I scroll down to the bottom, the cell (3, 0) is selected, and when I scroll up to the top, this is an other cell selected in the first section

Comment: You should prob be storing the selected cells and handling their properties/actions based on that stored array, instead of on the cells. Otherwise that will occur as if a selected cell is reused, the new cell will be selected too. Note though, I wouldn't store the cell, I'd store the object that is being used as it's data source, then work based on the data that is stored.

Comment: Can you see my update and tell me why this behavior continues while I no more use ```tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows``` please ?

Comment: @fredericdnd - are you updating `cell.checkButton.isChecked` and `cell.option.isSelected` in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: No, in `didSelectRowAt`and `didDeselectRowAt`, but I found the solution, I update the UI in `willDisplay`, because this function is called when the tableView is scrolled. See my solution in the initial post :) And thanks a lot for your help !