# TableView didSelect method and toggle

Tags: toggle

I have `tableView` I need to select 3 cells and and even I scroll it will be stay like. I can select 1, 2 or 3 cells but not 4 or more.When I select 4 cells nothing should happen. If there are 3 selected cells and I click one of them the cell which I selected should be deselected.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306096/2180785)?

Comment: What is a guy named imageView in the table view cell?  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a model, use the model. Modifying only the view is not persistent.

In the model add a property

```
var isSelected = false
```

in `cellForRowAt` set `isSelected` according to the model (assuming `items` is the data source array)

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
cell.isSelected = item.isSelected
```

Implement `willSelectRowAt` to handle the 3-items restriction by filtering and counting the selected items. If the method returns `nil` the row cannot be selected.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return items[indexPath.row].isSelected || items.filter{$0.isSelected}.count < 3 ? indexPath : nil
}
```

In `didSelect` toggle `isSelected` and reload the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

`indexPathsForSelectedRows` and `allowsMultipleSelection` is not needed respectively the latter must set to `true` permanently.

Comment: Add `CodingKeys` and omit the `isSelected` key.

Comment: As suggested in the linked question specify all keys **except** `isSelected`. And `isFavorite` is wrong anyway.

Comment: I made exactly same your codes + my override var selected in my cell class

Comment: My bad. Please see the edit in `willSelectRow`